# How fix an inverted execution order problem?

Tags: 7, forms, hooks

When the order of calling the implementation of a particular hook by different modules matter, you can change the weight of modules by tweaking system database table.

But it looks like I'm in a more difficult situation involving interaction of the field_group, and the clientside_validation modules with my custom module.

I use `hook_field_group_build_pre_render_alter()` provided by the field_group module to add some `'#states'` attributes to a field group form element.

The states I add change the `'#required'` attribute, besides other things. This form relies on a clientside_validation module suite to provide a JavaScript validation.

There is a brand-new module, clientside_validation_states which perfectly fits me, but I ran into the difficulties trying to make use of it. clientside_validation_states uses `#after_build`, which should be called after my code, but `hook_field_group_build_pre_render_alter()` is called in field_group by using a '#pre_render' FAPI attribute.

This together results in an inverted calling order. Do you have any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Can you move this to http://drupal.org/node/1619462 so we can keep track of it, or open a new issue at http://drupal.org/node/add/project-issue/clientside_validation?

Answer (score 2):

Posted this answer in the issue @attiks mentioned as well:

The easiest thing to do is to add the states in hook_form_alter() or in hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().

I got Clientside Validation to work on fields within a group, within a field collection.

Here's my code:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function fgtest_form_article_node_form_alter(&$form, $form_state) {
  $group = 'group_customgroup';
  $collection_bundle = 'field_my_collection';
  $fields = array_keys($form[$collection_bundle]['und'][0]['#group_children'], $group);
  foreach (element_children($form[$collection_bundle]['und']) as $delta) {
    $collection = &$form[$collection_bundle]['und'][$delta];
    foreach ($fields as $field) {
      $collection[$field]['und'][0]['value']['#states'] = array(
        'required' => array(
          "#edit-field-my-collection-und-{$delta}-field-make-required-und" => array('checked' => TRUE),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

And here's my setup:

**Node Article:**

[image: snap1]

**Field Collection field_my_collection:**

[image: snap2]